# Social question for using titles before name

Tags: politeness

I'd like to ask about English culture.
IF an (elementary) teacher address a parent without using Mr. Or Ms., but with first and last name only on their first email , what does it mean?

Isn't this supposed to be rude, even when the parent is addressing  the teacher with a title Ms.?

Comment: Which English culture? English is a language spoken in many different countries, some of them with widely different norms, especially for politeness. Or do you mean specifically England?

Comment: Coline, Canada.

Comment: You'll have to hope that somebody from Canada sees your question then. This is not really a language question.

Comment: Are you from England? How about your culture. I believe the manners shouldn't be that far.

Comment: This is not necessarily rude, no, especially if the teacher is not sure of the gender of the parent they are addressing and don't want to get it wrong. This is especially true in email, where a lot of formalities are just ignored.

Comment: Thanks Canadian. I am sure she know my gender. Does this make any difference? What if I address back the same using first and last name only, would you consider it proper and she would have slightly no discomfort?

Comment: It should be fine to either continue to use "Ms." or to match her usage of first name/last name.  Canadian culture is pretty informal, so you could probably even get away with just using her first name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not rude, and individuals will vary in their use of Mr or Ms.

Using "Dear Mr Kim" sets a very formal tone to an email.  It suggests that the teacher wants the relationship to be formal, professional, proper. A teacher might use this if the email contains a serious or negative message.

> Dear Mr Kim, I regret to inform you that your son swore at a teaching assistant and is therefore excluded from school for a period of one week.

Using "Dear Joe Kim"  sets a slightly less formal tone.  It suggests that the teacher wants a relationship based on shared understanding and goals, empathy. It invites the possibility of a warm relationship. It invites the parent to use the same form.

> Dear Joe Kim, I'm pleased to let you know that your son's contribution to our school festival of music was exceptional...

For a person in a caring profession, it would be quite normal for a teacher to use "Joe Kim" to address a parent in a first email.  It is polite without being formal.  On the other hand, it would be normal for the school's bursar to address parents as "Mr Kim", since the bursar has a financial relationship with the parent (and so formal, professional, proper), not a role of jointly caring for a child.

In short. This is normal, not rude. (Speaking from a UK perspective, but Canada is no more formal.)

Comment: Thanks for preventing a bigger commotion